# Why Javascript DOM has this strange behaviour?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to get the name input element by id using "name" and print it on the console:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name");
console.log(name);
var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
console.log(surname);

var select = document.querySelector("select");

console.log(select);

select.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
    console.log(select);
    var optionSelected = select.value;
    console.log(optionSelected);
    if (optionSelected === "beginner"){
        alert("it works!!!");

    }

})
```

but I get this on the first console.log:

`[object HTMLInputElement]`

As soon as I rename **var name** into **var obj** and do **console.log(obj)**, i get the correct element printed on the console:

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="hi">
```

This behaviour is quite strange because the surname input doesn't give any problem.

I'm using Visual Studio Code and Google Chrome.

Comment: @deceze I think that's the wrong dupe, it's more like [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return). Although there is `getElementById` too.

Comment: @VLAZ Nope, it's precisely *that* issue.

Comment: @VLAZ even I thought the same but marked dupe is correct. Refer this line: *As soon as I rename var name into var obj and do console.log(obj)*

Comment: @deceze You're right I...failed to read onwards. To exactly the sentence Rajesh pointed out. I'd leave the link (and my *shame*) here just for reference.